# npm start command giving cannot find module 'isexe' error

Tags: reactjs

C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app>npm start

> contact-manager-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'isexe'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\which\which.js
- C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\util\resolveCommand.js
- C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\parse.js
- C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js
- C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\react-dev-utils\crossSpawn.js
- C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\which\which.js:10:13)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\which\which.js',
  'C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\util\resolveCommand.js',
  'C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\parse.js',
  'C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\cross-spawn\index.js',
  'C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\react-dev-utils\crossSpawn.js',
  'C:\Users\bahub\Documents\React-Projects\contact-manager-app\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
  ]
  }

Comment: Did you install the app using `npm install` before starting it?

Comment: yup i did `npm install` before running  `npm start`